# Does the sequence $ x_n = ( - \frac{1}{n}) $ converge to $ 0$ in $\mathbb{R_l}$

Tags: general-topology

Does the sequence $x_n =(- \frac{1}{n})$  converge to  $0$  in $\mathbb{R}_l$  (lower limit topology) ?

My thinking :  I know that   $\mathbb{R}_l$   is  hausdorff , so  it will converge to unique limit points  so  I think that the sequence $x_n =( - \frac{1}{n})$  will converge to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x_n)$ be defined by $x_n=-1/n$.

- If $a\ge 0$, the open set $[a,\infty)$ contains no terms of $(x_n)$, so $(x_n)$ does not converge to $a$.$\\[4pt]$

  If $a < 0$, the open set $[a,a/2)$ contains only finitely many terms of $(x_n)$, so $(x_n)$ does not converge to $a$.

Hence the sequence $(x_n)$ does not converge.

Comment: If the sequence would converge, it would converge to $0$ (as it does in the coarser Euclidean topology) and then you don’t have to distinguish cases at all, but note $[0,1)$ is a neighbourhood of $0$ missing the entire sequence.